# Scrapy - externally configurable scraping rules

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'd like to define my scraping rules in an external file so that the core code will not need to change for each web site. The file will have several rules with each coming into effect for different web sites. I have external files for **start_urls** and **allowed_domains**, but would like to get your opinon on the best way to approach this for rules.

I'm thinking I could use xpath or regex rules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One option for extraction rules is to use [Parsley DSL](https://github.com/fizx/parsley)

[parslepy](https://github.com/redapple/parslepy) is an implementation of [the language](https://github.com/fizx/parsley/wiki) in Python (Disclaimer: I wrote parslepy)

With parslepy, you can use XPath and CSS selectors. You get a Python dict back.

Here's an example Hacker News spider with a special "_items" key in the rules to be used in callback as holding output items for scrapy:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import parslepy
import scrapy


class HnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hn"
    allowed_domains = ["news.ycombinator.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://news.ycombinator.com/',
    )
    parselet = parslepy.Parselet({
        "_items(tr.athing)": [
            {
                "title": "td.title > a",
                "source": "td.title span a",
                "rank": "span.rank",
                "--(./following-sibling::tr[1])":
                {
                    "score": "span.score",
                    "age": "span.age",
                    "comments": "span.age ~ a:last-child"
                }
            }
        ]
    })

    def parse(self, response):
        return self.parselet.parse_fromstring(
            response.body).get("_items", [])
```

The external file could be a JSON object with the rules. If you initialize the spider's `self.parselet` object with data from this JSON file, you can keep the callback as in the example above.

You can imagine using other special keys for links to follow.